# TopCoder UML tool: How to create Swimlanes?

Tags: uml

As the subject asks, how does one create a so called "Partition", commonly known as a Swimlane in the application?

I am creating an Activity Diagram!

Answer (score 0):

"The following elements are not supported by the current version of the TopCoder UML Tool and are not actively used in the TopCoder process.  However, these are often useful when building activity diagrams." Damn! The elements included Swimlanes.